# Problem with 74HC76, silly mistake or possible fake?

Tags: current, flipflop, short-circuit

I am a hobbyist and have been buying a few cheap ICs on AliExpress to play around with at home.  I know that there is some risk involved in buying these but I seem to have had mostly good luck so far.  A couple months back I received a batch of ICs that were definitely fake because they didn't have any coherent output.  When I contacted the seller they didn't reply and it was too late for me to initiate a dispute.  So now I try and sanity check what I receive right away.

Right now I am having a problem when testing some SN74HC76s (JK flip-flops).  I have a bench power supply with current limiting and when set at 5V, 20mA it just dumps all the current out of ground.  I've verified this with a DMM.  I don't think this is normal for this chip, is it?  The datasheet doesn't seem to indicate this.  Neither Q nor ~Q are going high.  I am hoping that you guys can sanity check my hookup to make sure I'm setting it up properly.  No matter what the reason for it failing to work I just want to understand why.  If it is a fake, I'd like to get better at realizing it sooner.  Thanks for any help.

Here's the [datasheet](https://www.datasheets360.com/pdf/1435646636716306996)

[image: Hookup]

Comment: Why does it seems upside down?

Comment: Your photo appears to be fake (there is no 74HC76 in it).

Comment: Yep, silly mistake.

Comment: Don't feel too bad about it. I have made the same mistake (old eyes, need better glasses!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That chip in the picture is L293D, not 74HC76, so it does not work.

Comment: Argh, ridiculous!  Thanks for the sanity check.  I got this mixed up with another IC I am going to test.  I'm not sure if I'm able to delete this question but if some mod is able to please go ahead.